# A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'Controller.HttpContext'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get the user that is using the application in the controller by doing this:

```
public class TableNameController : Controller
{
    private ConnectionString db = new ConnectionString();
    private string userIdentity = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1].Replace(".", " ");
```

When I do this, I get a red squiggly under `HttpContext` saying:

> A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'Controller.HttpContext'
>
> Cannot access non-static property 'HttpContext' in static context

How do I resolve this?

Comment: use instance constructor

Comment: @Lanorkin can you provide a little more explanation?

Comment: I think the message is clear, especially the first line. Do the initialization in the constructor or in a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use field initializer for what you trying to do, but you can easily use instance constructor for that:

```
public class TableNameController : Controller
{
    ...
    private string userIdentity;

    public TableNameController() {
        userIdentity = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1].Replace(".", " ");
    }

    ...
```

Comment: `User` would not have been set yet in the constructor. That line will only produce a value in an action.

Comment: @Nkosi just found that out by running it.. so I would have to declare this in each different action method?

Comment: @Nkosi that's another question

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid a lot of options, easiest is using Lazy<T> for example

Comment: Since this answer resolves the error message, I will mark as accepted but will ask another containing what I asked here in the comments.  That was my ultimate goal.