# Find User Outside of ActionResult Methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43002714/a-field-initializer-cannot-reference-the-non-static-field-method-or-property/43002894?noredirect=1#comment73095263_43002894).

Even though that answer resolves the error message I was receiving.. I would like to find the user that is currently using the application one time.. instead of having to write this inside of every action method...

```
var userIdentity = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1].Replace(".", " ");
```

I would like to have this at the top of the controller class before any ActionResult methods, that way I can just reference the variable in each action method instead of the entire line as seen above.. or even set this in a constructor that way I don't have to reference it at all.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create an Extension method

```
public static class ExtensionHelper {
    public static string UserIdentity(this HttpContext context)
    {
        return context.User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1].Replace(".", " ");
    }
}
```

usage in a Conttroller

```
var identity = HttpContext.UserIdentity()
```

You could do the same thing with a controller Extension if that seems cleaner.

```
public static class ExtensionHelper
{
    public static string UserIdentity(this Controller controller)
    {
        return controller.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1].Replace(".", " ");
    }
}
```

usage in a Conttroller

```
var identity = this.UserIdentity()
```

---

That said it would be cleaner if you used a proper IoC or DI framework and then had a Context class that you could inject that initiated this state if there was a user context. You could then inject this into your Controller instead of trying to extend your controller. My personal favorite is AutoFac but there are many out there and accomplishing this using almost any DI framework is relatively simple.

Comment: This will throw an exception depending on when it is called.

Comment: @Nkosi absolutely, the HttpContext and identity should all have the proper state and it is not safe to call from an async context its not executing on the thread that holds the Request.

Comment: @Nkosi - I am not going to write out a whole answer on it but the better alternative IMO is to use DI to inject a type that has an "execution context" where this could be included. That type could then be initialized with an injected HttpContextBase. Then there are no more issues and the controller becomes testable again.