# Cookies code outside of ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I want to use cookies to identify users. I have learnt how to do this, but I cannot have my code in a normal method and access that from ActionResult methods. I had thought of creating an ActionResult that gets the name and then returns the real ActionResult passing the name as a parameter. But this looks messy, specially considering some ActionResult methods have parameters already!

The first answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43003165/find-user-outside-of-actionresult-methods) looks quite promising. It proposes to create an extension method for HttpContext, which makes sense. This is my implementation:

```cs
public static class ExtensionHelper
{
    public static string UserIdentity(this HttpContext context)
    {
        string userName;
        HttpCookie cookie = context.Request.Cookies["userNameCookie"];
        if (cookie == null)
        {
            userName = CookiesCounter.ReturnNewestID();
            cookie = new HttpCookie("userNameCookie", userName);
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(31);
            context.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        }
        else
        {
            userName = cookie.Value;
        }
        return userName;
    }
}
```

But when I call

```
HttpContext.UserIdentity();
```

in my controller, I get the complaint that: "HttpContextBase does not contain a definition for UserIdentity and the best extension method overload requires a receiver of type HttpContext".

From my naive perspective (new both to extension methods and cookies) it looks like my code is a copy of that provided in the answer; what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Did you import the namespace for this class into the code where you are trying to call it? Extension methods are only visible to callers if the caller references the namespace.

Comment: I thought of that, but both classes are in the same namespace. I even referenced it explicitly for good measure, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should look at the type of `HttpContext` property. It is a `HttpContextBase` which means your extension parameter should be `this HttpContextBase` instead of `this HttpContext`

And then you need to be `using` the `namespace` where your extension class is located in to be able to use it

Comment: The namespace is correct. The first part sounds sensible, I'm looking into this now.

Comment: This solved it. Isn't it great when the solution is so simple? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Action Filters. Action filters are called before your action method on which they are implimented.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll look into that!