# MVC 5 - How can I set a DbContext connection string using a session variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My DbContext class:

```
public Accident_Reporting_LAX_2019_Entities(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
{
}
```

In my controller I am thinking I could set the connection string using a session variable, but I'm not having any luck trying to set that up.  I might be overlooking something simple because I'm not too experienced with MVC/C#.  If using the session variable is not possible in this context, what could be an alternative way to assign the connection string?

I'll post the pseudo-code for my idea and hopefully someone can correct/improve on it.  It doesn't have to be a session variable, I just need to be able to change the connection string.

```
public class IncidentController : Controller
{
    private static string facility = HttpContext.Current.Session["Facility"];

    private Accident_Reporting_LAX_2019_Entities LAX_DB = new Accident_Reporting_LAX_2019_Entities(facility);
}
```

The error that I get when trying to set the `facility` variable is "a field initializer cannot reference the non-static field method or property "Controller.HttpContext".

Comment: What's your use case that would have you wanting to use a session variable over a configuration value from, say, `web.config`?

Comment: I would like the variable to be able to change from one value to another, depending on the what the user selected it to be.  If the configuration variable in web.config can be changed, then that could also work.  I just need the end result to be the connection string changing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'Controller.HttpContext'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43002714/a-field-initializer-cannot-reference-the-non-static-field-method-or-property)

Answer (score 0):

To change configuration variable in web.config -

```
var configuration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
var section = (ConnectionStringsSection)configuration.GetSection("connectionStrings");
section.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString = "Data Source=...";
configuration.Save();
```

Answer (score 0):

HttpContext can't be access in static fields

Move everything inside the constructor like so:

```
private string facility;
private Accident_Reporting_LAX_2019_Entities LAX_DB;
public IncidentController (){
  facility = HttpContext.Current.Session["Facility"];
  LAX_DB = new Accident_Reporting_LAX_2019_Entities(facility);
}
```

Doing so allow each request to be initialize with your Facility variable